# Arithmetic series with irrational numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

How to check:

1. if $\sqrt{2}$,$\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{5}$ can be elements of the same arithmetic progression,
2. if numbers 11, 12 and 13 can be elements of the same geometric progression.

Elements aren't consecutive. Don't know how to start, need some directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first question try writing $\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2} = k_1d$ and $\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{3} = k_2d$ where $d$ is the common difference of the A.P. Can you see how to involve the property of irrational numbers to complete the proof here with contradiction?

> Hint: Divide $\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}$ with $\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{3}$

**Correction**

For the second one try to express the common ratio of the GP in two ways and equate them. You will get $$r = \left(\frac{12}{11}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}} = \left(\frac{13}{12}\right)^{\frac{1}{y}}$$ Can you see what to do next?

> Take the $(xy)^{th}$ power on both sides. You will get $12^{x+y} \not= 13^x11^y$ since $11$ and $13$ are prime factors both of which are absent from $12^{x+y}$

Comment: Check the proof for your second one...  You should get the contradiction from $12^{x+y} = 13^x \times 11^y$ for some natural numbers $x, y$.

Comment: @Macavity Ahh yes I made a blunder. Will fix that in the answer.